# Apollo Client React container add created element to paginated list of elements without refetching

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

This title is quite confusing, but I will try to explain the best that I can.  I have a situation where I am collecting and displaying a list of data elements from the server in React Native.  It uses a query that sends a GraphQL parameter to the server to limit the initial request to the first 15 elements.

```
query GetElements ($count: Int) {
    elements (count: $count) {
            id
            name
            tye
    }
}
```

As previously stated, this will query the main list with an initial count of 15 elements.

I have another page of the app that a user can create a new element on the backend using a different GraphQL query.

My question is: Is there a way to easily update the main list of elements to include the newly created element without performing any addition network requests?  In other words, I want to be able to simply add the new element to the main list of elements whenever the create command is successful.

The problem is: Apollo's `readQuery` command on the update proxy will not return to me the appropriate data set to update unless I know the variables that were send with the initial query; this includes the pagination `count` variable.

Comment: I am aware that this can be done well using the `updateQueries` option, but I know that the Apollo team is trying to move people away from that right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now define the key for the queries cache store like this:

```
 query AllItems($cursor: String, $limit: Int, $query: String) {
  items(cursor: $cursor, limit: $limit, query: $query) @connection(key: "AllItemsQuery") {
    count
    cursor
    has_next
    has_prior
    data{
      ...CoreItem
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will have to look into this.  This might be a good way to handle the situation.  So does this allow me to update the existing query as long as it contains the same connection key?

Comment: @Guardian_nw how will you update AllItemsQuery if items is deleted

Comment: guardian_nw, yes and use filters to define query vars to add to the key, thus allowing you to omit cursors etc.

@johndavedecano, using the same update flow as you would to insert a new obj, simply slice the store array.  http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-mutations.html#graphql-mutation-options-update

Comment: Lets say i have USER_IMAGES_CONNECTION as connection directive how can i query on that connection?

Comment: Are you asking how to access the query results from the data store so you can remove an item?  If so, you just use the DataProxy: http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#DataProxy

Answer (score 0):

if you would just like to receive the added item, it seems like you want subscriptions :: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/subscriptions.html

Comment: Thanks Kurt, but I don't think that is what I am looking for: I want to be able to update that list without any additional network traffic.